Terraform Snowflake Failed to install provider
I am trying to use Terraform to deploy some snowflake architecture. For testing purposes, my main.tf looks like the following:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "Snowflake-Labs/snowflake"
      version = ">= 0.87"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  role = "SYSADMIN"
}

resource "snowflake_database" "db" {
  name = "TF_DEMO"
}

When I try to "terraform init", I get:
Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing snowflake-labs/snowflake v0.92.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/snowflake-labs/snowflake: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: 403       
│ Forbidden returned from objects.githubusercontent.com

I don't know what the cause of this is, I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to it. I can imagine that since I'm behind a proxy, it could be the problem, but I'm unsure.

This sounds like a corporate environment issue related to firewalls/proxy. However, that would normally cause a timeout and not a 403, so I have to wonder if maybe your company also is using Github and you are authenticated as your corporate user as that may be causing this issue.

I don't know how to find this out. Is there a way to circumvent this?

It looks like Matthew Schuchard is right. I found some info about objects.githubusercontent.com - this domain are used by self-hosted agents in GitHub workflows. This means it may be a local issue within your company.
Quote:
" It serves as a storage location for certain artefacts and objects that are required during the execution of workflows. When using self-hosted agents, GitHub needs a reliable way to distribute files and data to those agents. objects.githubusercontent.com acts as a content delivery network (CDN) for delivering necessary resources to self-hosted agents, ensuring efficient and reliable access to artefacts and objects needed for the workflows to run successfully."
the link: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/58455
